# How to determine the biggest interval where f(x) is invertible and f(x)^-1 passes through P

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

I need some help here.

$$f(x) = \sin{(3x)} - 1$$
$$P = (-1,0)$$

Comment: I think you need to study the intervals of the inverse function i.e the derivative of the inverse function on the given interval

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make $\;\sin x\;$ we restrict its definition domain to $\;\left[-\frac\pi2,\,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ (though this is **not** the only interval that can be taken. It is just the most usual), and thus in this case we can takt

$$-\frac\pi2\le3x\le\frac\pi2\implies-\frac\pi6\le x\le\frac\pi6$$

and here $\;y=\sin3x-1\;$ is injective and onto $\;[-1,1]\;$,and its inverse is

$$\sin 3x=y+1\implies x=\frac13\arcsin(y+1)\implies f^{-1}=\frac13\arcsin(x+1)$$

Now just check that we actually have $\;P=\left(-1,\,f^{-1}(-1)\right)\;\ldots$ and justify all the above.

Comment: The reason you could restrict the interval in the first place is because it's a sine function right? Also, if I wanted to find the interval where the inverse function passed through a different point what would I have to change?

Comment: Yes, because it is a periodoc function and in that restricted interval it gets its whole image, and probably: for example, you could be asked to give, again, an interval where the function is invertible and it passes through $\;(-1,2\pi)\;$ , for example. Then the restricted interval could be $\;\left[\frac{3\pi}2,\,\frac{5\pi}2\right]\;$ ...